# Can rankT = rank$T^2$ implies $T = T^2$?

Tags: linear-algebra

*Note: this is a very elementary question on linear algebra, and there has been indeed some solutions on similar questions on this site, but most of them are too concise that cannot solve my question.

Suppose we have a linear transformation T : $V \to V$ and rank(T) = rank($T^2$)

Then we have dim({$T(v): v \in V$} = dim({$T^2(v): v \in V$} (definition)

Since {$T^2(v): v \in V$} is a subspace of {$T(v): v \in V$}, and their dimension equal, we  have

$\{T^2(v): v \in V\}$ = $\{T(v): v \in V\}$, i.e. R(T) = R($T^2$)

Then I can proceed no further since the range of these transformations equaling does not tell me about the relations of T and $T^2$

Comment: You can't go further because the statement isn't true. Think of reflections -- it has full rank but the square is the identity not itself.

Comment: MathJax tip: If you want curly braces for sets, you can use the commands `\{` and `\}`. Also `\dim` is a handy command here as well. If you want to create your own operators, you can use the `\operatorname{}` command, e.g. `$\operatorname{rank}(T)$` produce $\operatorname{rank}(T)$.

Comment: It *can*, but that doesn't mean it is true always which you have pieced together. Just a slight nitpick on the breakdown between typical language use and the way it is used in mathematics.

Comment: $T$ and $T^2$ always have the same rank when $T$ is nonsingular.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No!

As the linear transformation could be represented by a matrix.

We could take the $T: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ such that the matrix form of $T$ is
$$
A_T = 
\left(
\begin{matrix}
1 & 1 \\
0 & 1
\end{matrix}
\right).
$$
Then, the $T^2$ has matrix form as the following
$$
A_{T^2} = A_T^2 = 
\left(
\begin{matrix}
1 & 2 \\
0 & 1
\end{matrix}
\right),
$$
which demonstrates that $T \neq T^2$.

If you want to write out the formula for $T$. We can define $T$ as $T(x,y) = (x,x+y)$ then $\mathrm{rank}(T) = \mathrm{rank}(T^2)$, however, $T$ is totally different from $T^2$.